# How to get attributes from a post requested via the JSON API?

Tags: rest-api, json

I pick up the content of a post in my javascript, like so (Video is a custom post type):

```
var post = new wp.api.models.Video( { id: post_id } );
post.fetch();
```

This works. When I `console.log(post)`, I see the contents of the post, including many properties under `post.attributes`.

But, when I console.log(post.attributes), I only get `{id: "12345"}`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I access the properties of the post I retrieve?

Comment: Did you do something like `post.fetch(); console.log(post.attributes);` ?

Comment: Yes. That gives me only the ID in an object. Nothing else. But console.log(post) gives me the full object, including many attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that WordPress uses [Backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/) as its data model representation in their Javascript API Client.

Since `post.fetch()` is an async function and returns a promise then you'd have to do your logic/logging after the fetch is complete.

So you write:

```
post.fetch().then( function( p ) {
   console.log( p );
} );
```

LINKS:

[`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch)

Comment: Thanks. This indeed does work. So, if I understand this correctly, I can't access 'post', but I can access 'p'. :/

Comment: @MastaBaba you can access `post` too as by the time fetch is complete its attributes are already populated with data from the backend.

Comment: But that didn't work. That's what I was trying to do; I first would do console.log(post), which logged the full post, including all its attributes, then console.log(post.attributes), which only logged the the single id attribute. :/